# stubbing process.exit with jest

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs, spy

I have code that does something like

```
 function myFunc(condition){
  if(condition){
    process.exit(ERROR_CODE)
  }
 }
```

How can I test this in Jest? Overwriting `exit` in `process` with `jest.fn()` and returning it back after the test doesn't work, since the process exits

Answer (score 67):

The other suggestions in this thread would cause errors on my end, where any tests with `process.exit` would run indefinitely. The following option worked for me on TypeScript, but it should work on JavaScript as well:

```
const mockExit = jest.spyOn(process, 'exit').mockImplementation(() => {});
myFunc(condition);
expect(mockExit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ERROR_CODE);
```

The catch is that simply using `spyOn` meant that the original `process.exit()` function was still called, ending the process thread and hanging tests. Using `mockImplementation` at the end replaces the function body with the provided function (which is empty in my example).

This trick is also useful for tests that print to, say, stdout. For example:

```
const println = (text: string) => { process.stdout.write(text + '\n'); };
const mockStdout = jest.spyOn(process.stdout, 'write').mockImplementation(() => {});
println('This is a text.');
expect(mockStdout).toHaveBeenCalledWith('This is a text.\n');
```

This will let you test printed values, and have the added benefit of not messing up CLI console output with random linebreaks.

---

Just one note: As with any "jest.spyOn" call, regardless of using mock implementation or not, you need to restore it later on in order to avoid weird side-effects of lingering mocks. As such, remember to call the two following functions at the end of the current test case:

```
mockExit.mockRestore()
mockStdout.mockRestore()
```

Comment: mockImplementationOnce will complain in typescript as process exit expects to never return and here we are returning {}

Comment: One possibility would be throwing an error in the mock implementation, which would also have return type never: `const mockExit = jest.spyOn(process, 'exit').mockImplementation(() => { throw new Error('Mock'); });` Another possibility would be forcing the return type of the spy to "void" so that Typescript will stop complaining.

Comment: Nice answer!
PS: There is no need to pass an arrow function for `mockImplementation` unless you must set a variable on test scope and so on.

Comment: Typescript will not complain if you do `const mockExit = jest.spyOn(process, 'exit').mockImplementation(() => { return undefined as never })`;

Comment: I also found this useful to mock console.error() calls in the same way!

Comment: To get around the typescript error I used ```.mockImplementation((() => {}) as any)``` . Not an ideal solution as I am just telling Typescript to ignore the type but it means your solution works for anything you want to mock.

Comment: Not to face any Typescript errors with `mockImplementation`, just call that function without anything, if you don't need any special logic: `mockImplementation()` is an alternative to `jest.fn()`

Answer (score 7):

For most of the global javascript object, I try to replace with my stub and restore after the test. Following works fine for me to mock `process`.

```
  describe('myFunc', () => {
    it('should exit process on condition match', () => {
      const realProcess = process;
      const exitMock = jest.fn();

      // We assign all properties of the "real process" to
      // our "mock" process, otherwise, if "myFunc" relied
      // on any of such properties (i.e `process.env.NODE_ENV`)
      // it would crash with an error like:
      // `TypeError: Cannot read property 'NODE_ENV' of undefined`.
      global.process = { ...realProcess, exit: exitMock };

      myFunc(true);
      expect(exitMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ERROR_CODE);
      global.process = realProcess;
    });
  });
```

This help to avoid running the real `process.exit` to avoid crashing the unit testing.

Comment: It's probably some weird problem (probably mine) with Typescript, but I could not get the above to work -- kept complaining about reassigning the global.process = and the mock type not being a proper type of exit: etc. and then crashed when I ran it.. <shrug>

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me in terms of spying on `process#exit` *and* not getting type errors about the method signature of the mock implementation that required `// @ts-ignore`'ing:

```
const processExit = jest
  .spyOn(process, 'exit')
  .mockImplementation((code?: number) => undefined as never);
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem. Solved it with the code below

```
const setProperty = (object, property, value) => {
    const originalProperty = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object, property)
    Object.defineProperty(object, property, { value })
    return originalProperty
}

const mockExit = jest.fn()
setProperty(process, 'exit', mockExit)

expect(mockExit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('ERROR_CODE')
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with mocking process.exit before importing my module. So importing before mocking worked.

```js
const { foo } = require("my-module");

const realProcessExit = process.exit;
process.exit = jest.fn(() => { throw "mockExit"; });
afterAll(() => { process.exit = realProcessExit; });

describe("foo", () => {
    it("should exit the program", () => {
        try {
            foo();
        } catch (error) {
            expect(error).toBe("mockExit");
            expect(process.exit).toBeCalledWith(1);
        }
    });
});
```

(important never to return (throw) in mocked process.exit so foo doesn't continue control flow as if nothing happened)

Answer (score 2):

Mocking the implementation of **process.exit** can sometimes interfere with the control flow the code under test because now the process continues after **process.exit** call. Here is how to stub **process.exit** with jest and solve this problem:

```js
const mockProcessExit = jest.spyOn(process, 'exit').mockImplementation(((code) => { 
  throw new Error(`Process.exit(${code})`); // Forces the code to throw instead of exit
}));

describe('My Module', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockProcessExit.mockClear();
  });

  it('Should exit with 99', () => {
    expect(() => myFunction()).toThrowErrorMatchingSnapshot(); // snapshot: Process.exit(99)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `jest.spyOn` as this will call the original method as well:

```
const exit = jest.spyOn(process, 'exit');
//run your test
expect(exit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('ERROR_CODE');
```

Comment: This didn't work for me -- jest runs and then exits itself with the exit code being called..

Comment: I was able to get it working with
`const exit = jest.spyOn(process, "exit").mockImplementation(number => number);`