# Handling process.exit(1) with Jest

Tags: jestjs

I am writing my unit tests for NodeJS using Jest. 
A part of my code exits using `process.exit(1)`, so when trying to test it using Jest, the test terminates when it comes to this line with the error `Command failed with exit code 1.` which is the default behaviour of `process.exit(1)`.

Can anyone please tell how to work with Jest to handle this scenario and continue with the other tests?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [stubbing process.exit with jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46148169/stubbing-process-exit-with-jest)

Answer (score -1):

I think, throwing an error instead gives a more maintainable and testable code for you. Like:

```
if (err) {
  throw new Error("Some relevant error msg")
}
```

If you insist on using process.exit(1), you can test for [process.exitCode](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exitcode), which should be 1 in your case.

Comment: But process.exit(1) just terminates the test. It does not come back to my unit test where I can check for its value. Makes sense?

Comment: Well, process.exit going to shut down nodejs. You can't prevent that. https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit